# VB.NET - Getting a NaN result, can't figure out why

Tags: vb.net, math, nan

I'm trying to write a simple GPA calculator where the user enters a grade from an item on a combobox (A,B,C,D,F) and the credit hours of the course, and the calculation will output into a textbox. However, I keep getting a NaN result within the textbox and I can't for the life of me understand why. I've only got a bit of programming experience, so I'd appreciate any help!

```
    Public Class Form1

    Public points As Double, hours As Integer

    Private Sub btnRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRecord.Click

        Dim gpaPoints As Double
        Dim creditHours As Integer
        Dim grade As String

        If cmbGrades.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
            MsgBox("Please select a grade.")
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf txtHours.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please enter credit hours.")
        Else
            grade = cmbGrades.SelectedItem
            creditHours = CInt(txtHours.Text)
            gpaPoints = CalcGPA(grade, creditHours)
            points += gpaPoints
            hours += creditHours
            ClearList()
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Sub ClearList()
        cmbGrades.SelectedIndex = -1
        cmbGrades.Text = "Select a grade"
        txtHours.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Public Function CalcGPA(grade As String, creditHours As Integer)

        Dim gpaPoints As Double

        Select Case (grade)
            Case "A"
                gpaPoints = 4
            Case "B"
                gpaPoints = 3
            Case "C"
                gpaPoints = 2
            Case "D"
                gpaPoints = 1
            Case Else
                gpaPoints = 0

        End Select

        Return gpaPoints

    End Function

    Private Sub btnGpa_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGpa.Click

        Dim calcGpa As Double = points / hours

        txtGpa.Text = FormatNumber(calcGpa, 2)

    End Sub

End Class
```

I basically have the record button which works fine clearing the list and allows someone to enter a second grade, but the calculate button is not working and I can't figure this out. I sincerely appreciate any help.

Comment: Just a remark : your `creditHours` parameter is unused.

Comment: To help you debug this :  any calculation using a NaN will give out a NaN, and also 0/0 will also give NaN for floating point number calculations like in your case points / hours)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @pac0 - Could you elaborate by chance? Is it considered unused even though I have hours += creditHours and the variable converting the textbox to an integer?

Comment: This is probably not the cause of your problem, just a side note. But anyway, you are indeed calculating some value for creditHours in the btn_click handler, but when you call `gpaPoints = CalcGPA(grade, creditHours)`, it seems that you don't use creditHours at all in the function `CalcGPA` .

Comment: @pac0 You sir are a legend. Thank you so much. I used some logical thinking when you brought up the 0/0, and my calculations were off. Taking the case values and multiplying by creditHours fixes my problem and it calculates correctly. I actually understand it which is even cooler, programming is awesome. I sincerely appreciate your help.

Comment: glad it helped ! :)

Comment: You should set Option Strict On

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, if you are getting 'NaN's you can check for the following :

- A calculation with any NaN somewhere will give out a NaN
- The 0 / 0 division will give a NaN if it's with floating points number. You have a floating point division, so you can check here if your values are not zero when you do your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Private Sub btnGpa_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGpa.Click

   'Dim calcGpa As Double = points / hours '(**did you assign values here?** if not remove this)
   dim answer as double = 0

   CalcGPA(cmbGrades.SelectedValue, txtHours.Text )
    txtGpa.Text = FormatNumber(answer, 2)

End Sub
```